# How configured basler camera to don't get duplicate image

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I have configured the Basler camera (aca1920-40um) which is connected to the USB port, I have duplicate frames when I use PylonViewer software and I store a sequence of still images. What parameters should I change to prevent this from happening?
The parameters that I set after connecting camera to pc are:
Enable acquisition frame rate = active.
fps = 25 (acquisition frame rate); trigger = off; Exposure auto = off; exposure time = 1000 .

In the next step, I took the frame using OpenCV and c++ with a code similar to the following link, which again gives me a duplicate frame.
[Convert images from Pylon to Opencv in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43695811/convert-images-from-pylon-to-opencv-in-c)

Comment: Can you share the code snippet please?

Comment: I guess this is related to acquisition loop (camera) and capture loop (software) synchronization. If you are reading faster than acquisition rate it is guaranteed that you see duplicate images. And if you don't have synchronization, it is possible that you can see duplicate images when you read above "half" of acquisition rate. Try reading at 12.5 fps or lower. Or use some synchronization like "trigger".

Comment: @zahir I need at least fps = 25. This camera claims to be responsive to fps = 25. Do you know how to get this fps and what determines the acquisition rate?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and contacted Basler customer service about it. The issue you are running into is likely due to how you have the recording options set in PylonViewer.

Go to the Recording Settings and set 'Record a frame every' to 1 and select 'Frame(s)' from the drop-down list.
[screenshot of pylonviewer recording settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3Vxe.jpg)

This worked for me.  It was not at all intuitive that those setting applied to the 'Video', I thought it only related the the 'Sequence of still images' option given the layout of the UI.